# React/TypeScript: Creating a unified "notification" function that ties to a single component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to design my app so that all notifications tie in to a single "snackbar" style component (I'm using the material UI snackbar component) that wraps the app:

example

```
class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <MySnackbar >
        <App />
      <MySnackbar />
  }
}
```

truncated example snackbar class:

```
class MySnackbar extends React.Component<object, State> {
  public state = {
    currentMessage: { message: "", key: 0},
    open: false
  };
  private messageQueue = [];

  public openAlert = (message: string) => {
    this.queue.push({ key: new Date().getTime(), message})
    if (!this.state.open) {
      this.setState({ open: true });
    }
  }
  // other class methods...
  public render () {
    // render component here...
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can make it so that I can simply export a function that when called, has access to the "openAlert" function referencing the parent snackbar.

hypothetical child component:

```
import notificationFunction from "MySnackbar";

class Child extends React.Component {
  public notifyUser = () => {
    notificationFunction("Hi user!")
  }
}
```

I know there are libraries that do this, but its important for me to understand how they work before I use one. I have seen a few examples using global state (redux, react-context), but I'm looking to avoid using global state for this.

I have tried following some guides on creating HOC patterns, but I can't seem to design something that works how I want this to work. Is what I'm trying to do even technically possible? I know that I could make this work by passing the function down to every child as a prop, but that requires adding a field to every single interface and intermediate component, and is not very DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable React's way of doing that is `Context` (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

```
interface IContext {
  updateMessage: (newMessage: string) => void;
}

interface IProps {}

interface IState {
  message: string;
}

const SnackbarContext = React.createContext<IContext>({
  updateMessage: () => {},
});

class Snackbar extends React.Component<IProps, Partial<IState>> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "",
    };

    this.updateMessage = this.updateMessage.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SnackbarContext.Provider value={{ updateMessage: this.updateMessage }}>
        <div>
          <strong>MESSAGE:</strong> {this.state.message}
        </div>
        <hr />
        {this.props.children}
      </SnackbarContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  updateMessage(newMessage: string) {
    this.setState({ message: newMessage });
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  static contextType: React.Context<IContext> = SnackbarContext;
  context: IContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Create message</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.context.updateMessage(`Message with random number at the end ${Math.random()}`);
  }
}

<Snackbar>
  <Child />
</Snackbar>
```

There is also hooks experiment (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which may or may not be a future.

> I have tried following some guides on creating HOC patterns, but I can't seem to design something

HOC will not work here. Or all JSX.Elements will need to be wrapped in HOC. And it is more easy to pass callback function down the whole element tree instead of using HOCs.